# drop right menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm looking for a drop-right menu, not dropdown. Based on list of lists, ex html

```
 <ul>
 <li> item1
 <li> fold1 <ul><li> fold1it1 <li> fold1it2 </ul>
 <li> item2
 <li> fold2 <ul><li> fold2it1 <li> fold2it2 </ul>
 </ul>
```

When you mousover fold1, it would expand to the right right (drop right)

```
 item1
 fold1   fold1it1 fold1it2 fold2it3
 item2
 fold2
```

I'm looking for really simple to understand css example, or some kind of jquery plugin
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out, I'll still take any suggestions

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html><head>
<style type="text/css">
.dropRight {
    border: 1px solid red;
    display:block;
}

.dropRight ul, .dropRight li {
    margin:0 0 0 0;
    padding:0 0 0 0;
}

.dropRight ul li:hover , .dropRight ul li a:hover {
    background: #dddddd;
}
.dropRight ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
}

/* sub lists hidden by default */
.dropRight ul ul {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: none;
}

/* show the sub lists (children) */
.dropRight ul li:hover >ul {
    visibility: visible;
    background:yellow;
    display: inline-block;
}

/* sub list items drop right, not down */
.dropRight ul ul li {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

</style>
</head><body>
<div class="dropRight">
 <ul>
 <li> item1
 <li> <a href="#">fold1</a>
  <ul>
   <li> fold1it1
   <li> fold1it2
   <li> <a href="#">fold1it3</a>
  </ul>
 <li> item2
 <li> <a href="#">fold2</a>
  <ul>
   <li> fold2it1
   <li> fold2it2   
   <li> <span title="The Impossible Fold">fold2it3fold1</span>
    <ul>
     <li> fold2it3fold1it1
     <li> fold2it3fold1it2
    </ul>
   <li> <a href="#" title="messed up">fold2it3fold2</span>
    <ul>
     <li> fold2it3fold2it1
     <li> fold2it3fold2it2
    </ul>
  </ul>
 </ul>
</div>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at [fgmenu](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ipod_style_and_flyout_menus/) from the Filament Group.  Works with jQuery UI themes, in particular the flyout menus.  It also appears that [future work](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/Menu) on jQuery UI menus will be based on this work.

Comment: Thanks, but that is not what I am looking for , it drops down (right then down, still down, i just want right).